# Redirect should work whether in iframe or not.

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got a login.php page that typically is viewed in a lightbox-style iframe. User enters name and email, the form is submitted to itself (login.php) within the iframe, and if login succeeds then I redirect them to the desired page using:

```
echo "
    <script>
        parent.changeURL('{$returnlink}' );
    </script>
";              
exit;
```

In the parent page's `<head>` section is the function that makes this redirect work:

```
<script>
    function changeURL( url ) {
        document.location = url;
    }
</script>
```

However, if the login.php page is loaded in the parent window itself, *not* in the lightbox-style iframe it's designed to load in (not expected, but possible for it to happen), then this redirect function breaks, because in that case there is no parent, and actually it should be changing its own URL, not a parent's.

Is there a more durable php or javascript redirect code? Or a way to alter it to self-correct if it is not in an iframe?

Comment: You could put a simple check if `parent` is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using suggestions from @Tapas Pal, @Sumit Bijvanai and @yourdeveloperfriend, my now-working solution is:

```
<script>
    if(parent) {
        parent.window.location='{$returnlink}';
    }
    else {
        window.location='{$returnlink}';
    }       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(parent)parent.window.location=url;
else window.location=url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  if(parent)
    parent.changeUrl('{$returnlink}');
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking if you need an else?